# Is it possible to synchronously invoke an AWS Lambda function from Python Boto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto

This page shows only a method for asynchronous invocation.  I imagined there would be a synchronous invocation option.

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/awslamba.html?highlight=invoke

Apparently it is possible with .NET:

[How can I invoke an AWS Lambda function from my EC2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021386/how-can-i-invoke-an-aws-lambda-function-from-my-ec2-instance)

Comment: You can with boto3, http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) says to specify `InvocationType` as  `RequestResponse` for synchronous invocation

```
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='string',
    InvocationType= 'RequestResponse',
    LogType='None'|'Tail',
    ClientContext='string',
    Payload=b'bytes'|file,
    Qualifier='string'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do this.

```
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='string',
    InvocationType='Event'|'RequestResponse'|'DryRun',
    LogType='None'|'Tail',
    ClientContext='string',
    Payload=b'bytes',
    Qualifier='string'
)
```

http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke

Comment: Note InvocationType  'RequestResponse' will invoke synchronously, 'Event' is async